# Laravel - How to get data from a table related with pivot table

Tags: laravel, pivot, pivot-table

I have this model for `notifications` table:

```
class Notification extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'notification_user', 'notification_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

And this method in controller for getting data from `notifications` where id of `notifications` is related to a pivot table named `notification_user`:

```
$myNotifications = DB::table('notification_user')
            ->join('notifications', 'notifications.id', 'notification_user.notification_id')
            ->where('notification_user.user_id', $userId)
            ->where('notification_user.seen', 0)
            ->get();
```

the result of `$myNotifications` is correct but I want to use `Model` and its relationship instead of `DB`.

How can I get all records in `notifications` where each notification related to a specific user which is not seen by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `->withPivot('seen')` to the relationship:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany(User::class, 'notification_user', 'notification_id', 'user_id')
        ->withPivot('seen');
}
```

Then you can do:

```
Notification::whereHas('users', function ($q) use ($userId) {
    $q->where('id', $userId)->where('seen', 0);
})->get();
```

To avoid joining users, your other option is [whereExists](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-exists-clauses):

```
Notification::whereExists(function ($q) use ($userId) {
    $q
        ->selectRaw(1)
        ->table('notification_user')
        ->whereRaw('notifications.id = notification_user.notification_id')
        ->where('user_id', $userId)
        ->where('seen', 0);
})->get();
```

Should still be more performant, but not much more elegant.

Comment: Isn't any other approach there not to involve ourselves with User model and just get the result from Notification and its pivot table?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't. You could use `whereExists` with a raw subquery though.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define the same relation in User model as `notifications` and then:

```
$notifications = User::where('id', $user_id)->notifications()->where('seen', 0)->get();
```

Comment: I don't want to get anything from User model related to users table but only from `notifications` and `notification_user`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use with keyword for eager loading inside your controller.
like if you have any relation defined inside your model, just add a with('modelRelation') before your get() statement in eloquent.

Happy Coding.